# transfer certificate Self-Signed between 2 sandboxes

Tags: sandbox, migration-tool, migration, certificates

I'm looking for a way to migrate certificate Self-Signed between two unbound sandboxes. I saw that certificate are not metadata, so it's a bit harder than expected for me.

Comment: You can probably export the certificate and import in the other sandbox as described in this [link](https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_security_certificates.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you aayush, had not found your [link](https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_security_certificates.htm) before

Just for information, I go throught different problem when I try to follow this :

- Identity Provider (and my domain) must be activaded to avoid "Data not avalable" issue when trying to import certificate
- When importing, I got a an error "Insufficient Privileges". I switch to classic to avoid this error [Insufficient Privileges Certificate](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205098/insufficient-privileges-certificate)